# Laravel 5.4 - How to change a word in the json language file?

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel-5, lang

I am using Laravel 5.4.32 on Windows 10 (I know, I know... :P)

I use "en.json" as language files look like that:

```
{
  "Title 1": "Here is the first title!",
  "p 1": "The first text",
  "p 2": "Another text"
}
```

The problem is... I want to change only the text "The first text" by using an ajax request.

After that, I would like to save the file with the new text inside but within the same format. Nothing (except the text I want) can change in this file because I have to read it later.

Someone can help me please? What is the best Laravel (or just Ajax/Php) method to do that?

If you need more informations, just tell it me please. :)

Comment: can you post your code of how you approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Ajax or php.
**PHP Approach**

First, you need to decode it :

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('en.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Then change the data :

```
$data[0]['p 1'] = "new text";
```

Re-encode it and save it back in the file:

```
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('en.json', $newJsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MalemScha ! That's work! But could you tell me why the first and the last caracters are [ and ] instead { and } ?